# Order status changes to processing again after paypal capture funds

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal, payment, paypal-express

The problem I am having is that first order is processed and then when the funds are captured from PayPal,the order status is again changed to processing.But the order is already processed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

In order for a sales order to be complete it needs to be invoiced and also shipped. Once you have captured an order, it is invoiced, but still needs to shipped. If you have a downloadable product this shouldn't be a the case.

[Magento made a little flowchart for this:](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce-ee-order-status)

[image: magento flow chart]